# C++ using RAII to create an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, raii

Is there a way to use RAII when creating an array in C++, or do I have to resort to manual memory management via the "new" keyword?

EDIT: By request, some additional details:

First my disclaimer: I'm fairly novice at C++.

Now the details: I simply wanted to iterate through an existing array, SomeClass source[], and parse each element into a storage array, string results[].

So to create that storage string results[], do I need to say `string results[] = new string[source.size()]` or is there a way to avoid the "new" keyword here via RAII techniques?

It sounds like I'm hearing vector is the way to go.  Still, wondered if it's possible with a plain old array.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific about what you are trying to do.  A code example would be helpful.

Comment: What is the memory management you are looking for, which std::vector  can't handle for your case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++, especially since we're talking about RAII, we really shouldn't be using C-style arrays at all.  The Standard Library provides many containers with different properties that obviate most needs for C-style arrays.  By default, you should be using `std::vector<>` unless you have an understanding of the other containers and a compelling reason not to <sup>1</sup>.

Judging from your comments, it looks like what you're trying to do is build an array of string data.  This is simple in modern C++ -- just use a `std::vector <std::string>`.

```
int main()
{
  std::vector <std::string> myStrings;
  myStrings.push_back ("hello");
  myStrings.push_back ("goodbye");
}
```

This achieves all your mentioned goals of being RAII and no need to `new` or `delete` anything.  It also integrates very nicely with other Standard Library facilities, such as `find`.

I did say "obviate **most** needs," emphasis mine.  There is still occasional need to go old-school.  I won't discuss them here since if you actually *need* it you already know.  Which is to say, if you don't know you probably don't need it.

All that being said, `std::unique_ptr` [does support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) managing C-style arrays with special syntax:

```
std::unique_ptr <unsigned []> myArray (new unsigned [256]);
```

the array managed by `myArray` above will be properly deleted with `delete []` at destruction time.

Since [there is no `unique_ptr` analogue](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/) to `shared_ptr`'s `make_shared`, you will either have to use `new` to actually construct the array, or provide your own (or someone else's) implementation of `make_unique`

---

Sidebar:  `make_unique` will be added to C++14.

---

<sup>1</sup> **" you should be using std::vector<> unless you have an understanding of the other containers and a compelling reason not to"**

This isn't just my opinion.  It's also the general (unofficial) opinion of StackOverflow [as a whole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031496/why-prefer-stdvector-over-stddeque/19031874#19031874), C++'s creator Bjarne Stroustup, and the C++ Standard itself (23.1.1).

Comment: "you should use std::vector<> unless you know a good reason not to" - Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: @koodawg:  I did say that.  Are you suggesting I didn't, or just underlining the point?

Comment: @koodawg:  And in fact, the Standard itself has the same advice.

Comment: @JohnDibling By quoting Stroustrup I was confirming your answer!

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<T>` is an RAII array type. From the additional information you've given `std::vector<string>` is appropriate for your use.

---

> `string results[] = new string[source.size()]`

Just as an aside about arrays, this syntax isn't correct for C++. People teaching C and C++ often teach that arrays and pointers are the same thing, but this is not true and the syntax above shows one of the ways they differ.

The actual relationship between arrays and pointers is

- Arrays and pointers are distinct types
- In many contexts an implicit conversion from an array to pointer is applied. The conversion results in the address of the array's first element.
- pointer arithmetic is defined such that if a pointer points to an element in an array then you can get pointers to other elements of the array by adding and subtracting to the pointer value.
- In a some contexts writing an array type will result in a pointer type. In particular, function parameters declared to be of array types are adjusted to be of pointer type. E.g. `void foo(int[10]);` is effectively identical to `void foo(int*);`.

So the code you show is declaring an array and initializing it with a pointer. This will result in an error because there's no conversion from pointers to arrays.

Generally you should avoid raw arrays in C++; Arrays just have too many weird rules, such as the weird function parameter rule described above, the rules about when exactly the implicit conversion is performed, prohibitions on assignment and returning arrays from functions, etc. When starting out it's probably best to just stick with the `std::array` template for arrays with a size known at compile time and the `std::vector` template for arrays with a size not known at compile time.

Comment: @bstamour, I wouldn't call that RAII any more than a plain old `int`.

Comment: Hrm, true it doesn't technically acquire any resources. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector<string>` and `push_back()` each result string in to the vector. You don't have to use new unless you want to avoid vectors and manage memory by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple template would do the trick in the general case:

```cpp
template<class T>
class HeapArray {
    T* ptr = nullptr;
public:
    HeapArray(int size) { ptr = new T[size]; }
    ~HeapArray() { delete [] ptr; }
    operator T*() { return ptr; }
};
```

You use it as:

```cpp
HeapArray<std::string> results(source.size());
results[i] = "how cool is this";
```

basically the HeapArray object is automatically cast'd to its member pointer.