# Create an array/vector of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode

I'm trying to create an array or vector of objects. Most other stuff that I've found online has been about dynamically creating this, but I know the size that I need. I say vector or arrays because I believe either one will work for my situation (I'm comparing start and stop points) but any input onto which one will work better would be gladly welcomed as I'm pretty new to C++. My code below is my header followed by my main where I attempt to declare an array of objects, then I get this error: Variable length array of non-POD element type "Window." `posWsize` is a const int declared

```
#ifndef __Compare_Data_C____comp_fns__
#define __Compare_Data_C____comp_fns__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Window {
    int start, stop, length;
    double average;
    string strandID;

public:
    void setValues(int a, int b, string strand, int length, double avg);
};
#endif

int main()
{
    int posWsize = getSize(fwdWindowInput, "+", windowHeader);
    Window posWindow[posWsize];

    return 0;
}
```

`getSize` gets the size of my array. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If I can't do it this specific way that's ok, I just want to know how to properly create this array (or vector if appropriate) of objects. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<Window> posWindow(posWsize);`? See this [`std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Window> posWindow(posWsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule in C++, unless you have a compelling reason not to, [use a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031496/why-prefer-stdvector-over-stddeque/19031874#19031874).